# Enter Canada with 20 days left on Vistor visa

Tags: visas, canada, repeat-visits

I’m planning to visit Canada but by the time I get there I would have 20 days or less left on my vistor visa would that be an issue? I’m planning to extend it once I get there

The CIC website says it’s ok as long as it’s still valid at the time of entry but could the immigration at the airport deny entry for the fact that there’s only 20 or less days left on the visa ? 
And will I also need a return ticket to my home country ?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you think that airport immigration officers would do something different from what the Canadian government website says?  Are you worried that the website is wrong, or that the officers are poorly trained?

Comment: I’m worried because people have been saying different things about not being able to enter the country with a visa that has less than a month, I already spent three months in Canada and I’m planning to leave for a month and come back. I couldn’t get a hold of immigration call center to confirm otherwise I wouldn’t have asked.

Comment: Were those people speaking about Canada or some other country?  Different countries have different rules about expiring visas.  In your case, your recent visit to Canada could cause trouble, but the expiring visa will not.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134157/does-my-visit-have-to-end-when-my-visitor-visa-expires-or-can-i-stay-6-months

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What kind of trouble? I would like to be prepared.

Answer (score 1):

Your Canada visa needs to be valid on the day you enter Canada. Your allowed duration of stay is not related to the visa validity period. This you already found out yourself from the official source, so it's not clear why you continue to doubt it.

Normally you will be given six months. Note, though, that your passport must be valid for the entire duration of your stay in Canada. You should renew your passport if necessary before returning. If you don't, and your passport expires in less than six months, you will be given entry only until the passport expiration date.

But you can only [apply for a new visitor visa inside Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/apply-new-temporary-resident-visa-within-canada.html) if it is a study or work visa. For other types of temporary visitor visas (e.g. business, tourist, transit) you need to apply outside Canada.

You also should be aware that you have spent a large amount of time in Canada recently, so you may find it more difficult to convince the immigration officer that you will leave Canada at the end of your next visit.

Comment: What kind of difficultly will I be experiencing? I just would like to be prepared. Is there anything I need to carry with me, documents pics etc ..?

Comment: @K3nda If you spend large amounts of time in Canada then they may think you are trying to live there instead of being a simple visitor who will leave and go back to some other country. You should bring any documents that would prove that you do not live in Canada and have a good reason to leave.